# ¿Cómo hacer que me imprima estas letras pero sin repetirse?

Tags: java

Mi problema es que tengo un método llamado "llenar" el cual genera letras aleatorias y almaceno en una pila como muestro en la imagen 2 pero quiero que esas letras no se repitan. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? les agradecería me ayudaran.

Aquí dejo el código con el main entero:

```
package javaapplication15;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication15 {

int tope = 0;
//agregar el abecedario en un vector pila
char pilabc[] = new char[26];
public void llenar() {
    //char letra = 'A'; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        char c = (char) (Math.random() * 26 + 'A');
        if (tope <= 26) {
            pilabc[tope] = c;
            c++;
            tope++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("pila llena");
            break;
            
        }
    }
    System.out.println("valores agregados");
   
}

 public void mostrar() {
    for (int i = tope - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(" " + pilabc[i]);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  JavaApplication15 c = new JavaApplication15(); 
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  int opt=0;
   do {
        System.out.println("\n1 llenar\n"
        +"2 Mostrar");
        switch (opt = sc.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                c.llenar();
                break; 
            case 2:
                c.mostrar();
                break;
        }
    } while (opt != 2);
}
}
```

[image: Imagen del método llenar]

[image: Resultado del método]

Comment: Puedes crear un *ArrayList* con todas las letras, y las vas sacando al tiempo que imprimiento hasta que este vacío.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    private static final char[] pilabc = new char[26];
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      llenar();
      mostrar();

    }

    public static  void mostrar(){
        for (char c : pilabc) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }

    public static void llenar() {

        // llenar el arreglo con todas las letras en orden
        for (int i = 0; i < pilabc.length; i++) {
            pilabc[i] = (char) ('A' + i);
        }

        // iterar pilabc para intercambiar sus elementos
        // con otros en posiciones aleatorias
        for (int i = 0; i < pilabc.length; i++) {

            // generar una posicion aleatoria entre 0 y  pilabc.length
            int pos1 = new Random().nextInt(pilabc.length);

            // hacer un intercambio de los elementos en esas posiciones
            char temp = pilabc[i];
            pilabc[i] = pilabc[pos1];
            pilabc[pos1] = temp;

        }
        System.out.println("valores agregados");

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el código amigo , solo que al tratar de ejecutarlo me sigue mostrando repetidos

Comment: Estás seguro? porque cuando el arreglo se inicializa  todas las letras son únicas. Después solo se revuelven y no se agrega nada más.

Comment: Si, sigue mostrando repetidas.Con el random las desordena pero las duplica en diferentes pocisiones.

Comment: Agregué al código una comprobación que hice para asegurar que las letras no se repiten.

Comment: Si lo acabo de checar el problema es que tengo que primero mostrarlos con otro método llamado "mostrar" y tienen que verse desordenados y luego ordenarlos , le cuestión es que al mostrarlos en el otro método me los muestra desordenados pero repetidos algunos.

Comment: Agrega el código del otro método para revisarlo.

Comment: Tengo que esperar a que lo revisen , te lo mando por acá :

Comment: MÉTODO MOSTAR

public void mostrar() {
    for (int i = 1; i <=1; i++) {
        System.out.print(pilabc);
    }
}

Comment: TODO ESTA SUJETO A ESTE SWITCH CON DO WHILE´

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //CREAMOS UN OBJETO PARA LLAMAR LOS METODOS 
    JavaApplication15 c = new JavaApplication15();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int opt = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("\n1 llenar\n"
                + "2 Mostrar");
        switch (opt = sc.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                c.llenar();
                break;
            case 2:
                c.mostrar();
 break;
        }`
    } while (opt != 2);
}
}

Comment: Estoy revisando y el método mostrar ya esta agregado al código original que mostré desde arriba. Por si le es mas fácil copiar así  .

Comment: Sí, ya había visto ese método, pensé que lo habías modificado. En el cambio que hice no se usa la variable `tope` así que su valor sigue siendo 0.

Comment: Si de echo la variable esta por una cosa que estaba probando pero no es necesaria ,ya que como comenta el valor es 0 ;

Comment: Pero lo que quiero en si es lo que comente antes , solo poder imprimirlas sin que se repitan pero aleatoriamente.

Comment: Así: `public void mostrar() { for (int i = 0; i < pilabc.length; i++) { System.out.print(pilabc[i]); } }` ?

Comment: Si es ese , ese me imprime acomodadas pero quiero desacomodadas pero sin repetir

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta y agregué un ejemplo completo con ambos métodos.

Comment: Ok dejeme checarlos

Comment: Oye amigo muchas gracias de verdad ! .